# Addon issue with ofxOSC.h

Tags: c++, xcode, kinect, openframeworks, apache-synapse

I am facing an issue with integrating synapse with openframeworks in Xcode. the problem is that the file `synapsestreamer.h` cannot find `ofOSC.h`. I tried dragging the ofxOSC folder into the addon folder and it still would not work.

I am new to objective-C and this kind of programming and hence cannot find a solution to this. I have tried searching on the internet but in vain. I am attaching a screenshot of the same for your reference, kindly have a look and let me know as to how I should link the `ofxOSC.h` file with the `synapsestreamer.h`

```
#include "ofxOsc.h"
```

This throws an error even if I have the ofOSC in the addons section.

Comment: `ofxOsc` requires the header search paths in the project settings to be set correctly.  If you want to fix it manually, take a look at one of the osc examples included with the openFrameworks distribution, specifically the Build Settings / Header Search Paths to see what is included for `ofxOSC`.

Alternatively the recommended way to include addons in your project files is to use the Project Generator application included with the distribution.

Comment: @user3029547 slightly off-topic: you can use ofxOpenNI which has a sample on using skeleton data

Answer (score 0):

there is this awesome addon for xcode by Adam Carlucci that manage OF addon very well. https://vimeo.com/79061998
hope it solves your problem!